# How to build JSON array of different objects using Jackson?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I'm building an android app that saves info on incoming/outgoing calls in a `CallLog` class, incoming/outgoing SMSes in an `SmsLog` class, and bytes sent/received via a `DataLog` class. I made them all implement a `JsonLog` interface so I can create a single `ArrayList` of `JsonLog`s, hoping that it will be easily convertible to a JSON array of different objects via Jackson.

However, I kept getting this error whenever I'm deserializing the JSON file:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance
of com.project.pojos.JsonLog, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped
to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional
type information
```

How can I solve this? All `JsonLog` classes have a string attribute `type`, which is either `in_call` or `out_call` for `CallLog`s, `in_sms` or `out_sms` for `SmsLog`s, and `data` for `DataLog`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to have a type parameter in your JSON data or a custom deserializer to do the job.

The easier solution is the former, because you won't need to code that much, and it can be easily extended and from the JSON data you could simply tell which entry is what type.

#### Type information

If you have a `type` parameter:

```
[
  {
    "type": "SMS",
    "id": 1,
    "data": { }
  },
  {
    "type": "CALL",
    "id": 2,
    "somethingOtherData": {}
  }
]
```

Then in your abstract `JsonLog` class you can set the type mapping information:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(name = "SMS", value = SmsLog.class),
    @Type(name = "CALL", value = CallLog.class)
})
public abstract class JsonLog {
}
```

#### Deserializer

If you cannot have this type information in your JSON you need to write your own deserializer. In that deserializer you'll need to decide from the actual entry whether this entry is an `SmsLog` or a `CallLog`.

Comment: Because my `SmsLog` and `CallLog` classes both serve to hold two different types (one for incoming and outgoing), I guess it'll also be easier to just create separate classes for logs of incoming SMS and calls, and outgoing SMS and calls, right?

Comment: If you want to have your entries in one JSON array, then these two solutions could work. If you can have separate arrays for the SMS and the Call logs, then it's much easier.

Comment: Oh, well the reason why I'm putting them all in one JSON array is I'll have to upload them altogether as one from the mobile app. If I separated them in their own JSON arrays, I'll have to make multiple connections and calls to the server.

Comment: No, you can do that like this: `{ "sms": [ ], "call": [ ] }`

Comment: ^Ah, I get it. I think that was my initial design but I wanted to avoid the nesting JSON arrays and objects, so it's like this now: `[{"type": "in_call", ...}, {"type": "out_sms", ...}, ...]`

Comment: There is nothing wrong about that nesting. It's more clear (for my taste).